# Is there a namespace aware alternative to PHP's class_exists()?

Tags: php, namespaces

If you try using class_exists() inside a method of a class in PHP you have to specify the full name of the class--the current namespace is not respected.  For example if my class is:

```
 <?
    namespace Foo;

    class Bar{
       public function doesBooClassExist(){
            return class_exists('Boo');
       }
    }
```

And Boo is a class (which properly autoloads) and looks like this

```
   namespace Foo;

    class Boo{
       // stuff in here
    }
```

if I try:

```
$bar = new Bar();
$success = $bar->doesBooClassExist();
var_dump($success);
```

you'll get a false...  is there an alternative way to do this without having to explicitly specify the full class name ( i.e. `class_exits('Foo\Boo')` )?

Comment: Have you tried prepending the class name with `__NAMESPACE__` in your `doesBooClassExist()` method?  Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?  (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php )

Comment: @Crontab This could be done as you indicate if there is not another way that's already namespace aware--just a personal preference.  You should make this an answer.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that its correct for the class_exists to search not in the namespace.. If it checks directly in the namespace how you will be able to check for class outside any namespaces from inside?

Comment: @Ray Looks like a few others beat me to it over lunch.  =)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Prior to 5.5, the best way to do this is to always use the fully qualified class name:

```
public function doesBooClassExist() {
    return class_exists('Foo\Boo');
}
```

It's not difficult, and it makes it absolutely clear what you're referring to. Remember, you should be going for readability. Namespace imports are handy for writing, but make reading confusing (because you need to keep in mind the current namespace and any imports when reading code).

However, in 5.5, there's a new construct coming:

```
public function doesBooClassExist() {
    return class_exists(Boo::class);
}
```

The `class` pseudo magic constant can be put onto any identifier and it will return the fully qualified class name that it will resolve to.......

Comment: + This is a better approach

Comment: Shouldn't the backslash be escaped (per the [PHP namespaces FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.quote))?

Comment: Note that this can't be used with dynamic class names. It will throw **Fatal error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch** - but if they reside in the current namespace you can assemble the fully qualified class name by hand: `$fqcn = __NAMESPACE__.'\\'.$class_name`