# How do I check if there exists an object by the name as given in the user input (which by default is a string), in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I am a newbie in PHP.

I have

```
$input = readline("\nEnter object:");
```

to read the name of the object that the user wants the details of, to variable `$input`, which by default becomes a string.

I need to check if there exists an object named `$input`, in any of the classes that i have defined, and call functions accordingly,like

`$this->getObsDetails()` if it belongs to class Obstacles,

else 
`$this->getCharaDetails()` if it belongs to class Characters.

I cannot use `is_object($input)` or `get_class($input)` function as `$input` is a string.

How can I efficiently achieve this?

Edit: I have a GameObjects class, which is the base class for Characters and Obstacles classes.
I have a public function in GameObjects

```
public function printDetails() {

    /* 
    based on the class of the calling object,  which I intend to find 
    here itself using get_class($this), I intend to call respective functions as */

    $this->getCharaDetails();

    // OR

    $this->getObsDetails();    
 }
```

Now, outside the class using `is_object($$input)` I know if there exists an object named `$input`. But `$$input->printDetails()` or `$input->printDetails()` cannot be performed.

How do I do it?

Comment: I dont get the point. So, `$input` is a string right? How can you use it as an object if it's a string?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to instantiate classes given as inputs and run specified method of the class depending on the class name.

What I would do is make a common method called run and call whatever needed, inside..

As for example:

```
<?php

class Cylinder{
    public function run(){
        return $this->getVolume();
    }
    protected function getVolume(){
        // your stuffs here
    }
}

class Circle(){
    public function run(){
        return $this->getArea();
    }
    protected function getArea(){
        // your stuffs here
    }
}
```

Then, I would check if the user inputted class exists.. and call run method if it does..

```
<?php

$userInput = readline("\nEnter object:");
if(class_exists($userInput)){
    $obj = new $userInput(); 
    $neededData = $obj->run();
}
```

Is it what you are looking for? If not, then explain your problem in a clearer fashion..

Edit: if you are using `namespace`, then check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407370/how-to-check-if-class-exists-within-a-namespace) too.

Answer (score 0):

To check if class exists just use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

To check if is object just variable variables

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

```
is_object($$input);
```